# UIViewController to UITabBarController (Calling different UITabbars from UIButtons in the root UIVIewController)

Tags: uiviewcontroller, hyperlink, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

Note: I'm using monotouch.

Hello,

I'm trying to develop the following UI: UIVIewController (root) > UITabBarController, and I'm doing this programatically.

Actually, it's a simple question.

I'll have some UIBUttons in UIViewcontroller (root) and these buttons are gonna open different UITABBARController. E.g. BUtton 1 -> Open UITabbarController 1 (with 3 tabs). Button 2 -> Open UITabBarContoller 2 (with 4 tabs).

Does anybody know if it's truly possible?
What's the method that i should put in the event of the button? rootview.View.AddSubview(Tabbar)?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I do not quite understand the question.

Do you mean that you have a view that has some buttons and based on this, it will then show a UITabBarController with a specific tab selected?

Or do you mean that you have an existing UITabBarController with some view visible on the first page, and then you want to select from this page different pages?

Would you mind posting a screenshot mockup?

Comment: You can see the diagram photo in the following path: http://www.optiart.com.br/images/stackoverflow1.jpg

Comment: that's what I'm intending to do. I'll create UITabBarControllers programatically (this is a home automation software, so it's different for different houses).

Comment: I concluded that I'll use some different object to build the UI cause as I read at the Apple Guidelines document, the UITabBar was designated to be used in other cases I think... In the root view maybe... I'll try a different aproach to make the UI. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, display each UITabBarController modally with `PresentModalViewController` on your parent controller.

I think you would be better off using UINavigationController with UITableViews inside for the UI you mention, however.  It will make much more sense to the user, in my opinion.

Comment: I read about ModalViewControllers, but the book said that to open this kind of controller, this controller has to be in the screen temporarily. In my case, maybe the customer will stay in the TabbarController for a long time... So i guess it's not correct to use this, right?

Comment: It's ok for a modal controller to be displayed for a long time.  I think using a UINavigationController might make more sense in your case, however.  A navigation controller can have as many views as you wish pushed onto it, and the user get a clear back button to know where they are in the UI.

Comment: OK, see this link: optiart.com.br/images/stackoverflow1.jpg . I was trying to do exactly as it's drawn, but I cannot find a method to call the UITabBarController from the UIViewControllerObject. So now I'm considering use just one UIViewController and add Tabbar object instead of instanciate one UITabbarController. what do you think?

Comment: I think you need to consider dropping the tab bar.  Take a look at some of Apple's pics here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html  I think using a navigation controller will clean up your UI quite a bit.

Comment: Thank you...I understood the problem with multiple different tab bars. It was designated to be used in another case. I'll use something different as you told you. Tks again. Lyniker